# trouble storing & retrieving hashed password & salt from mysql database from java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to have secure passwords within my application but I'm having trouble with the authentication section. The code works for registering a user, generating a salt and hashing a password using the generated salt. But when i try to authenticate I always get a failed login. My problem is how to store the hashed password and salt in a mysql database and how to then retrieve it in java to do the authentication check. Any advice would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: How do you do it now?

Comment: It's been implemented before. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java#BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Usage: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/

Comment: talex I am yet to figure out how to do it...no matter what I store the data as in the database, when retrieving in java using getBytes() returns a different value each time.